# Connection reset by peer [errno 104] in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

I've seen and read a lot about this particular issue on the internet.
I am writing a simple chat server and client using socket in python for learning purpose mainly.

I've observed an issue here.

Here is my server code :

```
__author__ = 'pchakraverti'

import socket
import select
import sys


class NickSocketMap(object):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, nick, client_socket):
        self.nick = nick
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        NickSocketMap.count += 1

    @staticmethod
    def display_count():
        print "Total number of clients is %d" % NickSocketMap.count


host = ""
port = 7575
socket_list = []
nick_list = []
cnt = 0
recv_buffer = 1024


def register_nick(nick, client_socket):
    obj = NickSocketMap(nick, client_socket)
    nick_list.append(obj)


def process_request(request_string, client_socket):
    parts = request_string.split("|")
    if parts[0] == "set_nick":
        register_nick(parts[1], client_socket)
        client_socket.send("nick_set")
    elif parts[0] == "transmit_msg":
        broadcast_message(parts[1], parts[2])
    return 1


def broadcast_message(message, client_nick):
    for s in nick_list:
        if s.nick == client_nick:
            try:
                s.client_socket.send(message)
            except socket.errno, ex:
                print ex
            break


def run_server():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.bind((host, port))
    except socket.errno, ex:
        print ex
        sys.exit(-1)
    sock.listen(10)
    # add the parent socket in the list
    socket_list.append(sock)
    # keep the server alive
    while True:
        try:
            read_ready, write_ready, in_error = select.select(socket_list, [], [], 0)
        except select.error, ex:
            print ex
            continue
        for s in read_ready:
            # check if s is the parent socket
            if s == sock:
                # accept new connection and append to list
                try:
                    con, addr = s.accept()
                    if con not in socket_list:
                        socket_list.append(con)
                except socket.errno, ex:
                    print ex
            else:
                try:
                    # receive packet from connected client
                    packet = s.recv(recv_buffer)
                    if not packet:
                        socket_list.remove(s)
                        read_ready.remove(s)
                        for n in nick_list:
                            if n.client_socket == s:
                                nick_list.remove(n)
                                break
                        break
                    print packet
                except socket.errno, ex:
                    print ex
                    continue
                process_request(packet, s)
    sock.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

and here is my client code:

```
__author__ = 'pchakraverti'

import socket


nick = ""
host = "192.168.0.167"
port = 7575
sock = ""


def welcome():
    print "Welecome to SecuChat!"
    print "---------------------"


def init():
    nick = raw_input("Enter your chat nickname : ")
    print nick
    global sock
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        sock.connect((host, port))
    except socket.errno, ex:
        print ex
    sock.send("set_nick|"+nick)
    #sock.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    welcome()
    init()
```

In the client code, when I don't do the `sock.close()`, the server runs into an exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 102, in <module>
    run_server()
  File "server.py", line 84, in run_server
    packet = s.recv(recv_buffer)
socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

how ever, when I add that line, the problem doesn't occur.

Now I've two questions :

i) I've handled exceptions in the server.py, why is this exception not being handled and why is it crashing the code ? How can I make the server more robust and what am I missing ?

ii) What is the logic behind this crash and exception in relation to the `sock.close()` line in the client ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

i) Your try-except  block doesn't catch any exceptions.

The first argument to `except` must be the type of the exception you want to catch. `socket.errno` is not an exception class but a module. You need to catch `socket.error`:

```
 except socket.error, ex:
     print ex
```

It "crashes" your code because any exception that isn't handled somewhere in the call stack propagates outwards until it hits an `except`. If there is no handler the program is terminated.

ii) When the client terminates without closing the connection, a `RST` packet is sent by the TCP/IP stack of your OS. This is roughly the equivalent of hanging up a phone without saying goodbye. Python converts this into an exception with the text "Connection reset by peer". It simply means that since you called `read()` Python assumed you expect to receive something and when the connection suddenly disconnected, Python informs you of this by raising the exception.